# Laravel 5 - How to save sessions to database

Tags: php, mysql, session, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5. I want to save every visitor that enter to my web application as session to databases. But i don't want the session be deleted after X amount of time. I wast to have a database with all sessions.. since beginning of time.

Now i know that laravel has it own Sessions instance. I don't know if it is the same or not. i just want a database table with session for every visitor that visit my web application. And that this session will not be deleted at all.

What is the best way to build it? Let say a visitor that is auth or not auth enter to my app and play a game. i want to save it per session and related it to a auth user or not.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're mixing up HTTP sessions and some business logic. HTTP sessions are, by definition, ephemeral and can be terminated at any point by the server or the client. You probably want to create some concept called a "GameSession" and save those in your database. You can then - in the HTTP session - store a `game_session_id`, and if that does not exist, create a new GameSession for the current session. You could also apply some logic to look up a users previous game session if they're logged in.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "permanent session"; that is, you cannot with absolute precision pair a single user with a single game session without identifying them somehow (for example by telling them to log in and thereby identify them by their user id)